# Transfer function of buffer

Tags: transfer-function, buffer

[image]

Not really sure on how to proceed
I got (Vin - Vout)/10K + (Vin - Vout)/wc = 0

I need to determine the poles and zeros for the same
The motive is to understand the pole added by the capacitor at some freq ‘f’ which in turn helps stabilise the circuit.

I have done it for other circuits but can’t proceed for this one.

Any help would be appreciated
Consider some delta between V+ and V- (practical scenario)
The exact part is OPA197IDR

Comment: The TF will depend on the specific op-amp and the op-amp's input capacitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of this circuit. No current can flow into or out of the op-amp's input terminals so no current will ever flow through the resistor. Because of this there can be no potential difference across the resistor, so \$V_\text{out} = V_-\$.

Due to negative feedback \$V_- = V_\text{in}\$ resulting in

$$V_\text{out} = V_\text{in} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$H(s) = \frac{V_\text{out}}{V_\text{in}} = 1 $$

This system has no poles or zeros and the components are merely ornamental.

Comment: I agree about the current part as the buffer has high impedance input paths. 
The resistor & the cap is added for stability’s sake. The intent for asking about the TF so that I could try to understand how the components are achieving so. 
Is there any other way I could mathematically understand the same?

Comment: @Harkirat As I have shown, the transfer function is independent of \$R\$ and \$C\$, hence they have no influence on the stability of the circuit either. I suggest reading through this link. It can perhaps help more than I can: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt087/slyt087.pdf?ts=1689978607087&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Yep thanks! Just to point out as well it has already been used in a circuit irl. So hopefully I might find explaining this, although I'm totally with you on the 'ornamental' part

Comment: @Harkirat [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYgXu.png) of where you *might* see your subcircuit. All I did was to take it and draw a few more parts around it to produce a 2nd order, 1 kHz, low-pass filter. In this case, the feedback provides for balancing the input bias current.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking out time. The capacitor is to improve the phase margin. Now the doubt still remains about calculating the TF for the same in a practical case there is going to be some delta I'm between V+ and V-